# Reset dselect selection before package installation

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt

I was looking through the list of packages with `dselect`, but pressed <kbd>Return</kbd> twice by mistake, thereby making it confirm and quit the `[S]elect` option.

When I go to the `[I]nstall` option, it's now suggesting to install a number of new packages that I don't want (and that have nothing to do with what I was looking for in the first place).

Since I haven't proceeded with the installation itself, is there a way to reset the selection to what it was before I selected new packages, without going through the list one by one and pressing `-` for each package? (It doesn't matter if it's done via `dselect` or via another related command.)

**EDIT: (Adding an example)**

I've tried on another machine where `dselect` is installed. Let's assume that package `gnugo` isn't installed (that's just an example).

- Launch `delect` and choose `[S]elect` to get the list.
- Search for `gnugo` in this list (using <kbd>/</kbd>, if you're not familiar with `dselect`).
- Select it with <kbd>+</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd> to validate the suggestions and <kbd>Return</kbd> again to validate go back to the main menu (the mistake I made).
- Go to `[I]nstall`. It will now say:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  The following NEW packages will be installed
    gnugo:i386 libgpm2:i386 libncurses5:i386 libreadline6:i386 libtinfo5:i386
  0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 1,926 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 9,634 kB of additional disk space will be used.
  Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
  ```
- Here, choose not to continue (`n`).
- Quit `dselect`.
- `dpkg --get-selections | grep gnugo` yields nothing at all.
- Start `dselect` again, go straight to `[I]nstall` again, the packages will still be selected for installation.

Of course, I can go back into the `[S]elect` list, search for `gnugo`, press <kbd>_</kbd> to deselect it, but in a more complex case, you may have to go through the new packages list one by one.

`[I]nstall` in `dselect` is visibly a front-end to `apt-get install`, but I'm not sure where it gets its selection from. It appears `dpkg --get-selection` is not it.
As far as `dselect` is concerned, I'd like to reset it in a state where everything maked with `***` stays at it was, but what's now marked with only `**` (and not installed yet) goes back to `__`, without having to go manually through the suggested list from the `[I]nstall` menu.

**EDIT 2:**

This is clearly related to the content of `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, which contains this entry:

```
Package: gnugo
Status: install ok not-installed
Priority: optional
Section: games
```

If I change this manually to `Status: deinstall ok not-installed`, it disappears from the selection in `dselect` (which makes sense).

What I would like is a general way of turning whatever says `Status: install ok not-installed` into `Status: deinstall ok not-installed` (leaving packages saying `Status: install ok installed` unaffected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out `dpkg --get-selections` doesn't list what's marked for installation and not yet installed, but `dpkg -l '*'` does, and starts these lines with `in`.

As a result, the following line resets these selections:

```
dpkg -l '*' | grep '^in ' | awk '{ print $2 " deinstall" }' | dpkg --set-selections
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--set-selections`* argument to `dpkg`:

```
echo "<package-name> purge" | dpkg --set-selections
```

You can then use `apt-get dselect-upgrade` to apply your package selection.

---

If you need to find the packages that have been selected for install but not yet installed (so you can reverse that selection) use this:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ if ($2=="install") print $1}' | grep -vF "$(dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2}')"
```

You can get slightly fancier and pipe that back into `--set-selections`, thereby automatically deselecting anything that's not already installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | awk '{ if ($2=="install") print $1,"deinstall"}' | grep -vF "$(dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2}')" | dpkg --set-selections
```

---

*You can also use `dpkg --get-selections` to list all of the explicit selections. This will also show you the format that `--set-selections` requires.

Comment: I'd like a way not to have to write each package-name. As far as I can see, `--get-selections` doesn't list those packages that have been marked for installation via `dselect` but aren't installed yet.

Comment: @Bruno: I've updated my answer to make it more automatic.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work for me. The `dselect` selections don't show up at all via `dpkg --get-selections`. I'm not sure if I explained the problem correctly, but if select with `+` something with `dselect`, validate the selection, and then go to the `install` section, it will say "*The following NEW packages will be installed*" and a few packages (then asking whether to proceed). If I quit and go back to `dselect` later to install (or via the select list) they're still suggested, yet they're not at all in the `--get-selections` list unfortunately. That's the selection I'd like to reset

Comment: +1, even if it didn't quite work, some of the right elements were there, thanks. I'm still surprised `dpkg --get-selections` doesn't list those packages. (I'm not sure if it's an issue with this particular version: this is on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine.)

Comment: Those packages aren't explicitly selected then. Dependancies are never selected (in the dpkg/dselect sense) to be installed. All of those other packages that it's saying will be installed are just dependancies. If you don't want them you'll need to deselect the package that depends on them.

Comment: The problem is that they always come back when going back into `dselect` (they're flagged for installation in the list and will be installed next time you choose `[I]nstall`).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29)'s [search capabilities](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html) to obtain the list.

```
aptitude -F '%p' search '~ainstall !~i'
```

Pass the list to `dpkg --set-selections` to mark them as to-be-removed.

```
aptitude -F '%p deinstall' search '~ainstall !~i' | dpkg --set-selections
```

Aside: welcome to the 21st century, I suggest switching to Aptitude instead of Dselect.

Comment: `aptitude -F '%p' search '~ainstall !~i'` doesn't return anything at all (and `gnugo` from my example is still marked for installation in `dselect).

Comment: Interesting... It works on a Debian Lenny and an Ubuntu 10.04 but not on an Ubuntu 12.04... (I think it's time for a move to `aptitude` anyway :-) )